# how to Sort script by columns and remove repeated ones

Tags: text-processing, awk, sort, datamash

I have a file with almost 2000 lines. the file format is like this:

```
12 34
0 2
2 3
7 9
1 2
306 237
0 9
12 134
2 7
2 9
306 3
```

I'm trying to write a bash script to remove repeated first columns and organize by second column. I expect this output:

```
0 2 9 
1 2
2 3 7 9
7 9 
12 34 134
306 237 3
```

I tried some piece of code but I didn't get the desired output. how can I achieve that and what should I use?

Comment: Your output is sorted by first column.

Comment: Have you tried `sort` and `uniq`?

Comment: is there any options for these commands that organize other columns? in output i don't have 2 columns anymore.

Comment: Yes `sort` and `uniq` can work on fields. However I have just noticed that your description misses an important detail that is in the output: You are merging column 2.

Comment: with respect to `I tried some piece of code but I didn't get the desired output.` - if you show us what piece of code, the output it produced, and in what way that output is undesirable then we can help you with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sort` and `uniq` to delete the repeated lines and then use `awk` arrays indexed by the first column value, and then append to each value of the array each second column, for example:

```
sort test.txt | uniq | awk '{if(col[$1])col[$1]=col[$1]" "$2; else col[$1]=$2;}; END{for (i in col) print i, col[i]}'
```

being `test.txt` your input file.

Note that before adding a new column to the correct value of the array you have to check if the array is empty or not, just to add the space between values.

Answer (score 3):

Using `datamash`:

```
$ datamash -s -t ' ' -g 1 collapse 2 <file
0 2,9
1 2
12 34,134
2 3,7,9
306 237,3
7 9
```

This reads the space-delimited data, sorts it, and collapses the second column into groups given by the first column.

To replace the commas by spaces, pass the output through `tr , ' '`:

```
$ datamash -s -t ' ' -g 1 collapse 2 <file | tr , ' '
0 2 9
1 2
12 34 134
2 3 7 9
306 237 3
7 9
```

Would you want to sort the lines numerically, pass them through `sort -n`:

```
$ datamash -s -t ' ' -g 1 collapse 2 <file | tr , ' ' | sort -n
0 2 9
1 2
2 3 7 9
7 9
12 34 134
306 237 3
```

Alternatively, do the numeric sort first, and remove `-s` from the invocation of `datamash`:

```
$ sort -n <file | datamash -t ' ' -g 1 collapse 2 | tr , ' '
0 2 9
1 2
2 3 7 9
7 9
12 134 34
306 237 3
```

To get each individual line numerically sorted column-wise (apart from the first column), make sure that you original data is sorted not only on the first but also on the second column:

```
$ sort -k 1,1n -k 2,2n <file | datamash -t ' ' -g 1 collapse 2 | tr , ' '
0 2 9
1 2
2 3 7 9
7 9
12 34 134
306 3 237
```

(Notice the difference this made to the last two lines of output.)

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` you can do:

```
awk '{ found[$1]= (found[$1]? found[$1] FS $2: $2); };
END  { for (x in found) print x, found[x]; }' infile
```

join second columns having the same first column and hold in an associated array we name it `found`, at the `END` print the first column (which we were used it as the *array key* and we will access them by *`key`* we name if `x`), next their joined second columns (accessible by *`array_name[key]`*)

Answer (score 1):

Numeric sorting the file on its two fields and passing onto GNU awk/sed for further processing we get the desired o/p:

```
$ sort -n -k1 -k2 < file \
| awk '
    BEGIN { ORS = "" }
    prev != $1"" {
      if (NR>1) print RS
      print
      prev = $1
      next
    }{ print ORS, $2 }
    END { print RS }
' -
```

---

```
$ sort -n -k1 -k2 < file \
| sed -Ee '
  :a
  $!N
  /^(\S+)\s.*\n\1\s/s/\n\S+//
  ta
  P;D
'
```

**Output:**

```
0 2 9
1 2
2 3 7 9
7 9
12 34 134
306 3 237
```